# Python: Upload huge amount of files via FTP

Tags: python, upload, ftp, ftplib

I'm developing a python script that monitors a directory (using libinotify) for new files and for each new file it does some processing and then copies it to a storage server. We were using a NFS mount but had some performance issues and now we are testing with FTP. It looks that FTP is using far less resources than nfs ( the load is always under 2, with nfs it was above 5 ).

The problem we are having now is the amount of connections that keeps open in TIME_WAIT state. The storage has peaks of about 15k connections in time wait.

I was wondering if there is some way to re-use previous connection for new transfers.

Anyone knows if there is some way of doing that?

Thanks

Comment: It's trivial to reuse existing connections with `ftplib`. So trivial that I'm not even sure how to explain it. I could write a quick sample that creates a pool of threaded `ftplib` connections all servicing a queue full of paths or something, if that would help.

Comment: it is unclear why do you see 15K TIME-WAITs on the storage. If the cause of the TIME-WAITs is numerous ftp data connections (due to `storbinary()` calls) then the client should initiate the tcp connection closing (to indicate EOF) and therefore TIME-WAITs should be on the client side. If TIME-WAIT is 60 seconds (Linux) then 15K corresponds to ~250 connections (file uploads) per second sustained over several minutes. Do you actually see that many uploads? TIME-WAITs only consume memory (to prevent new connections with the same (source ip, source port, destination ip, destination port) tuples).

Comment: Yes, we are uploading around 125 files per minute ( maybe our time-wait is 120 seconds, I'll check that ). Anyway, I think using TFTP should be a better solution for our problem because tftp is more lightweight than ftp. I'll just need to patch the tftp server to auto-create the full path when uploading a file.

Comment: I've added a TFTP client and it turned out that TFTP is much slower than FTP because of the way the protocol is implemented, it doesn't opens too many connections as FTP does but it has a implicit flow control that is very slow. So I got back to my previous FTP implementation trying to improve it's performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a new answer, based on the comments to the previous one.

We'll use a single TCP socket, and send each file by alternating sending name and contents, as [netstrings](http://cr.yp.to/proto/netstrings.txt), for each file, all in one big stream.

I'm assuming Python 2.6, that the filesystems on both sides use the same encoding, and that you don't need lots of concurrent clients (but you might occasionally need, say, two—e.g., the real one, and a tester). And I'm again assuming you've got a module `filegenerator` whose `generate()` method registers with `inotify`, queues up notifications, and `yield`s them one by one.

client.py:

```
import contextlib
import socket
import filegenerator

sock = socket.socket()
with contextlib.closing(sock):
    sock.connect((HOST, 12345))
    for filename in filegenerator.generate():
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            contents = f.read()
            buf = '{0}:{1},{2}:{3},'.format(len(filename), filename, 
                                            len(contents), contents)
            sock.sendall(buf)
```

server.py:

```
import contextlib
import socket
import threading

def pairs(iterable):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*2)

def netstrings(conn):
    buf = ''
    while True:
        newbuf = conn.recv(1536*1024) 
        if not newbuf:
            return
        buf += newbuf
        while True:
            colon = buf.find(':')
            if colon == -1:
                break
            length = int(buf[:colon])
            if len(buf) >= colon + length + 2:
                if buf[colon+length+1] != ',':
                    raise ValueError('Not a netstring') 
                yield buf[colon+1:colon+length+1]
                buf = buf[colon+length+2:]

def client(conn):
    with contextlib.closing(conn):
        for filename, contents in pairs(netstrings(conn)):
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(contents)

sock = socket.socket()
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
with contextlib.closing(sock):
    sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 12345))
    sock.listen(1)
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        t = threading.Thread(target=client, args=[conn])
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
```

---

If you need more than about 200 clients on Windows, 100 on linux and BSD (including Mac), a dozen on less good platforms, you probably want to go with an event loop design instead of a threaded design, using `epoll` on linux, `kqueue` on BSD, and IO completion ports on Windows. This an be painful, but fortunately, there are frameworks that wrap everything up for you. Two popular (and very different) choices are [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) and [gevent](http://www.gevent.org).

One nice thing about `gevent` in particular is that you can write threaded code today, and with a handful of simple changes turn it into event-based code like magic.

On the other hand, if you're eventually going to want event-based code, it's probably better to learn and use a framework from the start, so you don't have to deal with all the fiddly bits of `accept`ing and looping around `recv` until you get a full message and shutting down cleanly and so on, and just write the parts you care about. After all, more than half the code above is basically boilerplate for stuff that every server shares, so if you don't have to write it, why bother?

---

In a comment, you said:

> Also the files are binary, so it's possible that I'll have problems if client encodings are diferent from server's.

Notice that I opened each file in binary mode (`'rb'` and `'wb'`), and intentionally chose a protocol (netstrings) that can handle binary strings without trying to interpret them as characters or treat embedded NUL characters as EOF or anything like that. And, while I'm using `str.format`, in Python 2.x that won't do any implicit encoding unless you feed it `unicode` strings or give it locale-based format types, neither of which I'm doing. (Note that in 3.x, you'd need to use `bytes` instead of `str`, which would change a bit of the code.)

In other words, the client and server encodings don't enter into it; you're doing a binary transfer exactly the same as FTP's I mode.

---

But what if you wanted the opposite, to transfer text and reencode automatically for the target system? There are three easy ways to do that:

1. Send the client's encoding (either once at the top, or once per file), and on the server, decode from the client and reencode to the local file.
2. Do everything in text/unicode mode, even the socket. This is silly, and in 2.x it's hard to do as well.
3. Define an wire encoding—say, UTF-8. The client is responsible for decoding files and encoding to UTF-8 for send; the server is responsible for decoding UTF-8 on receive and encoding files.

Going with the third option, assuming that the files are going to be in your default filesystem encoding, the changed client code is:

```
with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding()) as f:
    contents = f.read().encode('utf-8')
```

And on the server:

```
with io.open(filename, 'w', encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding()) as f:
    f.write(contents.decode('utf-8'))
```

The `io.open` function also, by default, uses universal newlines, so the client will translate anything into Unix-style newlines, and the server will translate to its own native newline type.

Note that FTP's T mode actually *doesn't* do any re-encoding; it only does newline conversion (and a more limited version of it).

Comment: It's a very good example. I'll try it tomorrow but the problem is that I need lots of concurrent connections ( there are about 40 clients sending files simultaneously ). Also the files are binary, so it's possible that I'll have problems if client encodings are diferent from server's

Comment: First: 40 is not too excessive for threading, at least not on linux, Windows, and Mac/BSD. If you might need a few hundred in the future, that's a different story. In that case, look into using a epoll/kqueue event loop (linux/Mac/BSD) or IO completion ports (Windows). The easiest way to do that is with a good networking framework. If you start with simple threaded code, you can turn it into simple gevent code with only a handful of changes. On the other hand, you may want to start with something like twisted right off the bat. Whatever you're comfortable with. The point is a custom protocol.

Comment: Second: FTP doesn't do any magic with encoding. It does do some magic with line endings, but that's trivial to do yourself in Python 2.x, and not very hard in 3.x. If you really do need to reencode on the fly… I'll edit the answer to show how.

Comment: In FTP I'm transferring as binary files, that's why I don't need to care about encoding. The python example is using python's string functions to format the output string so it's possible that some encoding issues may arise...

Comment: @filipenf: In Python 2.x, `str.format` doesn't do any encoding unless you pass it `unicode` objects (or use locale-based format types like `n`), which I'm not doing. (That's not true in Python 3.x, but in 3.x you wouldn't be using `str` anyway, you'd be using `bytes`.)

Comment: @filipenf: Am I right in assuming that Python 2.7 is a requirement? I just realized that you've never confirmed it, and it was really just a guess…

Comment: Actually we are using python 2.6

Comment: @filipenf: In that case, you need to explicitly use `'{0}:{1},{2}:{3},` instead of `'{}:{},{}:{}'`… but otherwise, I don't think I used any 2.7-specific stuff in the answer. I'll do a quick pass over it and edit anything that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reuse connections with `ftplib`. All you have to do is not close them and keep using them.

For example, assuming you've got a module `filegenerator` whose `generate()` method registers with `inotify`, queues up notifications, and `yield`s them one by one:

```
import ftplib
import os
import filegenerator

ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.example.com')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('/path/to/store/stuff')

os.chdir('/path/to/read/from/')

for filename in filegenerator.generate():
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        ftp.storbinary('STOR {}'.format(filename), f)

ftp.close()
```

---

I'm a bit confused by this:

> The problem we are having now is the amount of connections that keeps open in TIME_WAIT state.

It sounds like your problem is not that you create a new connection for each file, but that you never close the old ones. In which case the solution is easy: just close them.

---

Either that, or you're trying to do them all in parallel, but don't realize that's what you're doing.

If you want *some* parallelism, but not unboundedly so, you can easily, e.g. create a pool of 4 threads, each with an open `ftplib` connection, each reading from a queue, and then an `inotify` thread that just pushed onto that queue.

Comment: I already have the pool of threads ( actually with 3 ) and a main thread using libinotify. Each thread has it's own FTP connection, but for each storbinary it spawns a new socket ( that's how ftp works, it allocates a new connection for the transfer in both passive and active mode ). What I want, but I don't know if it is possible is that the 'transfer' connection be spawned just for the first call to storbinary, and reused for the subsequent.

Comment: @filipenf: I think it's not quite legal to do what you want, because a data connection is for a batch of files that you want to transfer at once… but it would probably work with most servers, at least in passive mode. And if, on the other hand, if you want to upload a whole directory as a batch, I think that _is_ legal.

Comment: So, if you want to take advantage of that, and `ftplib` can't… you will need to fork [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/ftplib.py), monkeypatch it, or use a different FTP library. Do you need help with that, or were you just asking whether there's some hidden feature in `ftplib` that you couldn't find?

Comment: Finally, I still don't see the problem. Unless you're transferring a huge number of tiny files, the setup/teardown costs should be nothing compared to the transfer cost. And, even if you _are_ transferring a huge number of tiny files, as long as you close the data connections properly, there shouldn't be a problem anyway.

Comment: OK, reading the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959) more carefully: the server is allowed to return `226`, shutdown the socket, and issue a `425` error (active) or open a new connection (passive) on the next command. And, while the RFC seems to leave open the possibility that a server could do otherwise, I'm not sure how it would. (It needs to detect EOF somehow, and for file structure/stream mode/image representation, you can't do that inbound.) Testing with a few different servers, they all shutdown the socket. Which means what you want to do is probably not possible.

Comment: my case is exactly that of huge amount of tiny files. I'm receiving 600mbps of 1mb files and I need to forward them to the storage at the same rate. I've changed some sysctl options to reuse sockets and so on - that improved a little bit but it's not enough. Now I'm thinking in creating a server script that receives the files on the sotrage side. Anyway, thank you for your attention.

Comment: Really, 1MB is more than big enough that an FTP server ought to be able to keep up with it just fine. If not… then yeah, you probably want a different protocol. TFTP lets you use UDP for the data transfer, which might save your setup/teardown costs; HTTP PUT lets you send data over the same connection as control; but I think writing your own simple custom protocol may be easiest—e.g., just alternate sending the filename as a netstring, then the data as a netstring, with trivial acks in the other direction.

Comment: I've tried TFTP but despite being UDP it is much slower than ftp ( because the protocol uses an odd congestion-control mechanism ) so I've switched back to FTP and did some adjusts in systcl parameters. Basically I set this: net.core.rmem_max = 12582912
net.core.wmem_max = 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 5000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1

Comment: @filipenf: Have you tried writing your own trivial protocol as I suggested before? If you just need to send a large batch of small files as fast as possible (although again, I don't think 1MB is that small), it's going to be hard to beat sending a single size prefix before each file, all over a single TCP socket. (I wouldn't bother trying to build on top of UDP here, if the problems with TCP are only because you're opening and closing 600 sockets, because just using one continuous socket will fix that.)